# Passing instance variables from lib module to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an API call in module in my lib folder, which return a variables I need to use in my view. 
Example: I define the following in my module

```
module ProdInfo
  def get_item_info(id) 
    @url = "Blah"
  end
end
```

My controller:

```
class RecommendationsController < ApplicationController
  require 'get_prod_info'
  include ProdInfo

  def index
    @product = Product.find(params["product_id"])
    get_item_info(@product.id)
  end
end
```

I am trying to call @url in my recommendations view, however its not being called correctly. If I puts @url in my module it prints out the correct url, but if I do the same in my controller, nothing is outputted.

Comment: I'm thinking about you problem, for now you can just return the url in your method an do in you controller: `@url = get_item_info(@product.id)`

Comment: Why are you requiring `get_prod_info` for a module named `ProdInfo`? It's odd to have those names mismatch. Did you remember to restart your server after changing your module?

Comment: my lib file is called get_prod_info.rb, should it be titled the same as my module? Yup, made sure to restart my server after making changes to my module

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially Kaeros' comment expanded into code in both places.

You just need to be saving the variable in your controller instead of in your lib folder. Your file in lib should not know about your model's needs, and it will be just as happy returning a value without knowing where or how to save it.

```
module ProdInfo
  def get_item_info(id) 
    # in your comment you said you have multiple values you need to access from here
    # you just need to have it return a hash so you can access each part in your view

    # gather info
    { :inventory => 3, :color => "blue", :category => "tool"} # this is returned to the controller
  end
end
```

Rails 3 also has a config variable that allows you to specify paths to load, and I believe the default includes the lib path. This means you don't need all of your `require` entries. you can just call the `Module#method` pair.

```
class RecommendationsController < ApplicationController
  # require 'get_prod_info'
  # include ProdInfo
  # => In Rails 3, the lib folder is auto-loaded, right?

  def index
    @product = Product.find(params["product_id"])
    @item_info = ProdInfo.get_item_info(@product.id) # the hash you created is saved here
  end
end
```

Here's how you can use it in the view:

```
# show_item.text.erb

This is my fancy <%= @item_info[:color] %> item, which is a <%= @item_info[:type] %>.

I have <%= @item_info[:inventory] %> of them.
```

Comment: I have multiple variable defined in my `get_item_info` method which I need to use in my view.

Comment: so just have `get_item_info` package it into a hash and then you can access it all in the view. I'll update the code.